# how to Show address fiels in new form registration for Customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-address, address

I created a new form registration for customer and according to group, they will be redirected to a form.

I added the fields of address in the first one by adding this code at `customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But when I tried the same for the second form by adding below:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register_2">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
        <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

I got an error, also I have tried to `setShowAddressFields(true)` in phtml, but I got the same error too [image]

Comment: have you created `customer_form_register_2` referenceBlock ?

Comment: i have created  a form and called register2  under my theme/Module_customer/templates/form and i called this template in my newmodule layout